# SpreadsheetApp to Fusion Tables - End to End Tutorial

Tags: google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables, google-sheets-api

I've been wrestling with this for a few days on-and-off, and have read many many helps and articles on the topic, but some are apparently out of date, and all appear to be assuming certain required steps along the way. Here's an example:

https://github.com/entaq/GoogleAppsScript/tree/master/FusionTables

It assumes you have a token passed to the app via the DoGet, and have all the OAuth settings in place.

Now I may be alone here, but when it comes to OAuth (which appears essential), the do
cumentation seems to weave and wind but doesn't provide specific leads as to the choices required (what kind of Client ID do I need? 'web app' or 'service account'?).

Am I over-complicating things? I can get *a* token, but when I send the request, the

```
{ "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "message": "Invalid Credentials"
```

I've scoured the web for an idiot's guide, but this one eludes me. Any suggestions out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's now a native [Fusion Tables service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/fusion-tables) in Apps Script. That eliminates the need for the the OAuth dance and in general provides a much cleaner experience.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rod, this definitely looks more friendly. Not sure why Google allow so many legacy forms to remain in the documentation without guidance.

Now however, I am getting the error:
"Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."

Do I need to authorize Billing and enter all the information in order to get this working? Also I'm not sure what to do with the Console Client Settings, 'Authorized Javascript origins' & 'Authorized redirect URI'

Any experience with SpreadsheetApp > Google WebApp implementation?

Comment: I believe that error means that the FT API itself needs to be enabled. If you go to https://cloud.google.com/console/project and either create a project or use an existing one. Click on the project and then on "APIs" in the left nav. You should see a list of available APIs. Find Fusion Tables and set its status to "ON".

Comment: Nope, I didn't have to do anything with billing.

Comment: Good to know, thanks Rod, though I'm at a loss to know what I need to do to get this working, looks like this module still has serious flaws.